# Probability proof by Prhana Sanoo

Tags: probability

http://i66.photobucket.com/albums/h274/apolllos/prob_zpsy7h53c6y.jpg

I understand the first line in the proof, I'm unclear about the second line.

Those curly brackets denote a set, and they are being multiplied, so the product of the two sets is the Cartesian product.

For the third line, I don't understand how the sum was eliminated from the left side of the equality but not the right.

Any help is appreciated, if possible a step by step approach to understanding the problem would be nice.

Thanks.

Comment: They are not sets. They are just brackets in this context. The author uses the binomial theorem to expand both sides and then compares coefficients to conclude the proof. I think a better way would be to see the combinatorial significance of the theorem. Consider a group of $m$ boys and $n$ girls from which you need to select a group of $k$ people. One expression for the number of ways is $\dbinom{m+n}k$. Also, you can first pick $r$ of the $k$ people from the boys and the rest from the girls, which gives $\displaystyle\sum_{r=0}^k\binom mr\binom n{k-r}$ ways.

Comment: This result is known as the [Vandermonde's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde's_identity) and there are several generalizations to it in the linked article.

Comment: Your explanation is very clear, I understood it in seconds.  Thank you.

Comment: actually isn't the product of two sums the sum of the product of the original terms?

Comment: Yes, we do have $(\sum_i a_i)(\sum_j b_j)=\sum_i\sum_j a_ib_j$, but for the product of generating functions, you're not summing all terms. You're actually gathering the coefficients of $x^k$ in the newly obtained single series. For that, we have, $$\left(\sum_{i=0}^m a_ix^i\right)\left(\sum_{j=0}^n b_jx^j\right)=\sum_{k=0}^{m+n}\sum_{j=0}^k a_j\,b_{k-j}x^k=\sum_{k=0}^{m+n}\left(\sum_{j=0}^k a_j\,b_{k-j}\right)x^k$$